# Mapping SQL join result into object

Tags: c#

I have an SQL query that returns a list of `orderHeader` joined with its orderLines. What I want to do is to be able to map the result of this query into an object `orderHeader` with a field `List<orderLine>`. I have the following code below and it successfully maps `OutboundNumber`,`OrderDate`, and `Status` however it leaves `orderLine` as null. How do I make it so that the columns joined from the `orderLine` table is mapped properly?

Query:

```
SELECT TOP (50)
,odh.[outbound_order_number] AS OutboundNumber
,odh.[creation_dt] AS OrderDate
,odh.[outbound_order_status] AS Status
,odd.[outbound_order_number] AS OutboundNumber
,odd.[outbound_order_line_number] AS OutboundLine
,odd.[outbound_order_status] AS Status
,odd.[stock_product_id] AS StockProduct
FROM[outbound_order_header] as odh
JOIN outbound_order_detail as odd
ON odd.outbound_order_number = odh.outbound_order_number
WHERE conditionhere;
```

orderHeader:

```
public class orderHeader
{
    public long OutboundNumber { get; set; }     
    public Int16 Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public List<OutboundOrderLineDTO> orderLine{get;set;}
}
```

orderLine:

```
public class orderLine
{
    public long OutboundNumber { get; set; }
    public long OutboundLine { get; set; }
    public Int16 Status { get; set; }
    public long StockProduct { get; set; }
}
```

Main

```
var OutboundOrderHeaders = DbContext.Context.Database.SqlQuery<OutboundOrderDTO>(testString, parameter);
var OutboundOrderHeadersList = OutboundOrderHeaders.ToList();
```

Comment: Any reason why you're not using the built in mappings of (EF?) to do this? Normally you don't write your own join query, you just tell EF(/whatever orm) "order header has many order detail, order number references order number" and let the ORM worry about doing the join

Comment: I was advised not to use EntityFramework because we will be dealing with millions+ data and EF wouldn't be ideal for that.

Comment: You can use Dapper.net nuget package, but it requires two different queries for header and line. You can map query result directly to classes.

Comment: EF was just an example, hence why I said "whatever orm". You'll get more accurate feedback if you tell us what you use.  This is not an endorsement, but I work on a live stock trading system with tens of millions of records and EF is fine. Like anything you can use it well an appropriately and it will be great, or inappropriately and it will be terrible. Anyone who has swayed your decisions with a simple "EF can't handle millions of records", especially when you can find out that it's deployed in countless enterprises across the world, should be ignored because their argument lacks focus

Comment: I was using EF before but when dealing with the million rows I kept on coming across a memory leak. Perhaps we're doing it wrong. The comment on EF being inappropriate for large records was something I came across as an answer to a stack overflow question as well.

@CaiusJard

Comment: We're getting sidetracked from the main issue. You appear to be using an ORM. You haven't said which one. Giving us incomplete info is unhelpful. Most ORMs deal with the joining and populating hierarchical object graphs for you, once you tell them how the data relates. If your ORM does, tell us why you're not leveraging that function

Comment: How can it map the `orderHeader` values correctly? If you expect multiple `orderLine` values your `ToList()` would generate a list with duplicate 'orderHeader' objects. Is that not the case? The relationship between `orderHeader` and `orderLine` is 1 to many, so mapping from this join won't work like this. You should create a unique list of `orderHeader` and fill each item with its `orderLine` objects.

Answer (score 0):

This will create a list of `orderHeader` objects, each containing a list of `orderLine` objects.

```
orderHeader current = null;
var itemList = new List<orderHeader>();

foreach (var item in OutboundOrderHeaders)
{
    if (current == null || current.OutboundNumber != item.OutboundNumber)  // Try to match orderHeader item
    {
        current = new orderHeader()
        {
            OutboundNumber = item.OutboundNumber,
            Status = item.Status
            OrderDate = item.OrderDate
            orderLine = new List<orderLine>()
        };

        itemList.Add(current);
    }

    current.orderLine.Add(new orderLine()
    {
        OutboundNumber = item.OutboundNumber
        OutboundLine = item.OutboundLine
        Status = item.Status
        StockProduct = item.StockProduct
    });
}
```

You should check your query, since it has some naming conflicts (`Status` of orderHeader and orderLine, for instance).